# Sails + angular routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, angular-routing

> I have a simple $routeProvider on my assets/js/app.js file
>
> (Html file are in assets/pages)
>
> The code is:

```
angular.module('easyTrack',['authService','ngRoute'])
  .config((function($httpProvider,$routeProvider,$locationProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
      templateUrl:'index.html'
      //controller:'MainController',
      //  controllerAs:'main'
    })
    .when('/login',{
      templateUrl:'pages/login.html'
    })
    .when('/signup',{
      templateUrl:'pages/signup.html'
    });
  

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');

  }));
```

> I try to used this with my **sails**  application but sails doesn't
> work at all with my simple routeProvider
>
> There is any configuration i must do on sails to use angular route
> provider?
>
> Thanks

Comment: what do you mean doesn't work well, please write clearer explanation of the problem

Comment: fix the word ,and i mean that :when i navigate to localhost:1337/login it's not show me the login.html page...

Comment: Do you have the same problem with the other routes, like signup for example?

Comment: Yes, any of the routes doesn't working.
It looks that the angular routing doesn't do nothing

The index.index is the only page that i see but i didn't know if it's from the " '/' " role of the angular routeProvider or by sails it's self...

Comment: is server configured for html5mode? If not you need to turn it off and use hash in url's

Comment: @Yossi, since index file shows, then, I think the routing is fine. Try to put the login.html and signup.html in the same folder of index file

Comment: I try this but it still doesn't work, i think the the index.html come from the sails serving (not from the angular routeProvider '/' role) because even  if i change the '/' role to other page like login.html i didn't see this...
Something in the sails framework make this behavior and block the using of the angular routeProvider